# Why is c(1:10)[NA] the same as rep(10,NA)?

Tags: r

There are a variety of ways of indexing things in R. Most of them make sense in context.

However, I cannot figure out what the rationale behind

```
> c(1:10)[NA]
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

What is going on here?

Comment: `c(1:10)[NA]` is *not* the same as `repeat(10,NA)`? The latter command is invalid.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein Fixed - I meant replicate

Comment: @SvenHohenstein I make no assertion to the contrary. I'm just stating the code I *think* the OP meant to post.

Comment: What do you *expect* to happen here?

Comment: @MrBones `replicate` just evaluates an expression `n` times. In this case you are evaluating `NA` which evaluates to.... `NA`.

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon I was looking for the easiest way to make 10 NAs.  `replicate(10,NA)` appears to create the same thing - are you suggesting that semantically they're different?

Comment: Yes. Use `rep(NA,10)`. `replicate` is a wrapper around `sapply` and is very inefficient to do what you want. `rep` would the canonical way to do this (you could also do `x <- NA; length(x) <- 10`)

Comment: `replicate(10,NA)` creates a logical vector while `c(1:10)[NA]` creates an integer vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This form of indexing is specifically mentioned in the docs (see `?"["`):

---

> #### NAs in indexing
>
> When extracting, a numerical, logical or character NA index picks an
> unknown element and so returns NA in the corresponding element of a
> logical, integer, numeric, complex or character result, and NULL for a
> list. (It returns 00 for a raw result.)

Comment: I wasn't aware that `?"["` was possible.

Comment: @MrBones  `?"anything_at_all"` is possible.